# How to automatically turn on wifi hotspot on laptop

Tags: fedora

**Edit 2:** I'm using fedora 30 on my **laptop**, *I want to share internet from laptop to mobile*.

Is there a way to turn on wifi-hotspot for internet sharing automatically on boot?

When I log in I've to open wifi-settings and from menu select turn on wifi-hotpost daily as I've to connect my mobile to it.

I saw a post here that suggest to set the value from false to true `autoconnect=true` in the file 
`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`

But there is no such file. Please guide.

**Edit 3:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Normally one might expect that the mobile phone has an internet connection and acts as a WiFi hotspot for a laptop. But in your question I get the impression that the laptop would have the internet connection and  share it to the phone? The answer depends on which device does the sharing and which one uses the shared connection.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for info, I need to make laptop as wifi-hotsport so i can use its internet on my mobile. Please see edit2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new service file using a text editor. Open a terminal and run the following command to create the file:

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/wifi-hotspot.service

In the text editor, enter the following lines:

```
[Unit]
Description=Wi-Fi Hotspot

After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nmcli connection up Hotspot

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

Replace `Hotspot` with the name of your actual Wi-Fi hotspot connection, usually the `Hotspot` is the deafult.

3. Save the file and exit the text editor
4. Enable the service to start on boot by running the following command:

> sudo systemctl enable wifi-hotspot.service

Restart system and the hotspot should auto connect after network is online.

Comment: on F37 this will not work. for some obscure reason 
nmcli c up Hotspot
fails to properly bring up the hotspot complaining it cant connect
but it still works from gnomw-control-center
Is it possible to find out what gnome control center is doing differently to make it work ?

Comment: @louigi600 No idea man, not very techy in linux. As mentioned in the answer, maybe the hotspot ID / Name is not the same so try to figure that out first.

Comment: even with the uuid instead of the name it won't work ...
I had a partial success in I create the a new hotspot and then start it ... but it only worked once and then I was unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

In the hotspot settings menu, there should be two checkmarks:

- "Connect automatically" near the top: when checked, this is equivalent to the `autoconnect=true` setting.
- "Available to all users" at the bottom: without this checkmark, the configuration information is stored in your user-specific GConf + Gnome keyring data, and is not accessible to NetworkManager unless you've logged in. When this setting *is* checked, the connection information gets stored to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory, and NetworkManager will be able to use it as soon as the system boots up, whether or not you (or anyone else) is logged in on the laptop.

So, make sure **both** of these checkmark settings are enabled.

Disclaimer: I may know some things about NetworkManager but haven't tried Fedora 30 at all. Feel free to downvote if this is incorrect.

Comment: There is no checkbox option in wifi-hotspot settings. I'll attach screenshot tomorrow. the hotspot on is just a dropdown toggler.

Comment: Images added, please check

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ nmcli con up id "Hotspot"
$ nmcli connection modify Hotspot connection.zone trusted
```

Comment: It starts the hotspot but doesn't persist on reboot.